# creating a matrix of function to aid readability

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I have a matrix on which I have to solve the characteristic equation, where each element is a combination of several function of variable x. I have the explicit formula for each function that allow me to work with the matrix but the problem is that the expressions are extremely long and readability is a nightmare. I wish to know if there's a way to define each function in my matrix like: `f(x) = "expr of f", g(x)='expr of g'` and so on ... and use them so that the result is:

```
M = [[f(x)+2*g(x), e(x)**2, ...], ...]
```

where I can than do `sympy.solvers.solvers.solve(M.det(), x)`.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possibility, ideas to get you started:

```
eqs = [x, f(x), f(x) + g(x), sin(x), f(x)/g(x)]

def who(e):
    return ','.join(str(i.func) for i in ordered(e.atoms(Function)))

from collections import defaultdict
reps = defaultdict(list)
for i in eqs:
reps[who(i)].append(i)

r = {}
for k,v in reps.items():
if len(v) == 1:
    r[v[0]] = 'n/a'
else:
    for i,vi in enumerate(v):
    r[vi] = '%s_%i'%(k,i)

[i.xreplace(r) for i in eqs] -> ['n/a', 'f', 'f,g_0', 'sin', 'f,g_1']
```

In your case let `eqs = flatten(M)` and the final step would be `Matrix(M).xreplace(r)` (or `M.xreplace(r)` if `M` is a Matrix and not a list of lists as shown).

Note: if you *only* want certain functions you would have to use `e.atoms(Function) & wanted`.